# OneLogin SP initiated SSO with SameSite Lax by default causes user to be redirected to OneLogin Portal, not SP

Tags: onelogin

The normal flow is that the user is redirected from the SP (Service Provider) to OneLogin to enter username/password. Upon success, the user is redirected back to the SP.

But this does not work when using browser flags:

- In Chrome, SameSite by default cookies is enabled
- In FireFox, network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault = true

In this case, the user is redirected to the OneLogin portal instead of the SP.

Is OneLogin ready for when this change is made by browsers?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

The samesite cookie issue might be something with the SP.setting the cookies' samesite flags and I know OneLogin has done extensive workwith their flags to prepare for this.

Comment: The user is redirected to the OneLogin portal. This is not the expected behavior.

Comment: The expected behavior is to redirect back to the SP. This is how it works today and has worked since we started using OneLogin. Setting the SameSite Lax by default flag changes that established behavior.